# Why the_content doesn't work in wordpress single.php

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My code:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 
        <div class="posts" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <h2> 
              <?php the_title(); ?>
            </h2>
            <div class="entry">
                <?php the_content();?>
            </div>                  
        </div><!--post end-->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <h3>no content</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I put the code into my customed wordpress theme file single.php. Why it can't output the post content, it can output the post title. thank you.

Comment: Does this happens in all posts? Does it happens with a default theme (Twenty/10/11/12)?

Comment: i put  <?php the_content();?> in a default theme,it's ok. why?

Comment: did i miss something?

Comment: in twentyeleven theme,it can output the post content.

Comment: It may not even be hitting the single template, can you check if it is?

Comment: Compare the two files, you should be able to find why. Also, the code you posted is incomplete, what's before that `<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>`? You can [edit] your Question to add information.

Comment: before is <?php get_header();?>
and
  <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

Comment: Schoffelman, it invoke the right file, because it output the else part. <h3>no content</h3>

Comment: @down1337 can please post your file structure, i test your code and it showed `the_content`

Comment: which   file structure? my theme?

Comment: If it outputted '<h3>no content</h3>' then it could not have outputted the title as you have claimed unless it is using a different file.

Comment: @down1337 did you try my answer below?

Comment: it's ok.ps:i found a weird thing, if i put the code after get_sidebar() my code is ok.

Answer (score 8):

You can try the following to see if it works instead of `the_content`

```
<?php echo wpautop($post->post_content); ?> // content with p tags
<?php echo $post->post_content; ?> //without p tags
```

Also an option

```
<?php echo wpautop( get_the_content() ); ?> // content with p tags
```

see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

When developing Wordpress themes it's advisable for you to switch the debug mode (found on your installation's root in `wp-config.php`) to true. This will alert you if you have any errors.

In your case, try out the `<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`.
Also, this may sound a bit dumb, but do you actually have posts? Not pages or rather content in that post?

Answer (score 0):

Many a times i have come across queries from developers or first time theme developers about not able to show `the_content()` on their custom template page.
The issue is that the_content() function runs inside the WP loop so for example

```
if (have_posts()) {
while (have_posts()) {
the_post();
the_content();
}
} ?>
```

This will work, but in some cases you want to call the function outside the loop – the solution for that is:

```
echo $post->post_content;
```